# Do there exist continuous maps from the Sphere to the Plane which preserve the Hausdorff Measure of all sets with some Dimension between 1 and 2?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

It's well known that there do exist area preserving maps between the sphere and the plane.

It's well known there do NOT exist distance preserving maps between the sphere and the plane.

So naturally one can ask if Hausdorff $2$-measure can be preserved and Hausdorff $1$-measure isn't preserved then is there some $1 < \theta < 2$ such that Hausdorff $\theta$-measure can be preserved.

My expectation is that either measure preserving maps exist for all $1 < \theta \le 2$ or no measure preserving maps exist for $1 \le \theta < 2$. Any other behavior would be certainly surprising and or interesting.

### Some Ideas of Mine:

A related question might be to ask for maps from the Sphere to itself which preserve a particular Hausdorff Measure. This question might be a bit more tractable.

Suppose you fix the sphere along an axis $A$. And divide the surface of the sphere up into slices each of which can be independent rotated. So the map of the sphere can be viewed as a map along the axis and at each point of the axis an angle is indicated for how much that particular slice rotates.

[image]

We can characterize these maps from the sphere to itself by looking at functions from $[-r, r] \rightarrow [\pi, -\pi]$

As long as ALL the slices are rotated the same angle, you get an isometry which preserves $1$-measure. Which we show below as a green function from axis-space to angle space

[image]

Now the minute this green curve is no longer constant, the implied map stops preserving length. We know that for any smooth function we put on here the implied map will preserve area. I want to believe that (and I don't have a proof of this) for any continuous function with hausdorff measure $\le 2$ the implied map between spheres will preserve area. It would be beautiful but perhaps unsurprising if we stretched this idea in 2 dimensions to say that any continuous function with hausdorff measure $1 < \theta < \tau$ from axis to angle space preserves the Hausdorff $\tau$ measure on the sphere. But these ideas are far from rigorous and might even be completely wrong.

Comment: Your title question is different from the question in the body. Are you preserving *measure* or *Hausdorff dimension*?

Comment: Measure, i corrected the title to reflect this. I am looking for a dimension $1 < \theta < 2$ such that the maps preserve the measure of sets with dimension $\theta$

Comment: OK, good, now say with *some* dimension :)

Comment: Changes made :), I don’t like my title. I think it’s very verbose (my fault). I’m going to think about ways to compress it without losing information

Comment: Actually, there are Lipschitz maps from sphere to plane which preserve lengths of all rectifiable paths. This is somewhere in Gromov's book on PDRs.

Comment: PDR or PDE? It seems that gromovs book on PDEs has a reference to isometries per this mathoverflow answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15292/why-cant-there-be-a-general-theory-of-nonlinear-pde

Comment: As I said, PDRs, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-02267-2

Comment: Note that Gromov's theorem **suggests** that the answer to your question is strongly positive in the sense that for every $\alpha\in [1,2]$ there exists a continuous map $S^2\to E^2$ preserving the Hausdorff $\alpha$-measure. But, Gromov's setup is different from yours since he works with prameterized paths (hence, the lengths is given by integration) and you are working with subsets. I suggest, in few days you ask at MO.